# jQuery Traversing to add and remove HTML content

Tags: jquery, traversal

Having trouble getting to this span tag to add and remove HTML content for the toggle arrow.

```
$('h3 + p').hide();

$('h3').click(
function() {
$(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
 });

if ($('p').css('display') == 'none') {
      $(this).closest("span").html('&#9658');
 }
 else {
      $(this).closest("span").html('&#9660');
 } 


<h3><span></span> TITLE</h3>
<p> this content will toggle</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modification to your code, which is I think what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/qXSnC/1/

```
$('h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next().stop().slideToggle('normal').toggleClass("hidden");

    if (!$('p').hasClass('hidden')) {
          $(this).find("span").html('&#9658');

     }
     else {
          $(this).find("span").html('&#9660');
     } 

 });
```

Comment: Yes, closest() finds the next match in the ancestry.  Since span was a child of $(this) in your example, it wouldn't have found it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('p').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).closest("span").html('►');
 }
 else {
      $(this).closest("span").html('▼');
 }
```

Comment: The problem is not the if condition that works fine, when using .closest("span") to traverse the DOM, that's not working to reach the span.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I've come up with:

```
$('h3 + p').hide();

$('h3').click(function() {
    var t = $(this),
        p = t.next();

    t.find('span').html(p.is(':visible') ? '►' : '▼');

    p.slideToggle('normal');
});
```

I've created a working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VwVwd/).